# Handling Large Data Set Points in Leaflet and Node

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am working with angular js and leaflet js on client side and node js as server.

I am using https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport to add & remove layers which contain large number of data points.

I have all the data points in mysql, I fetch data points and I send them to the client side, then at the client level I use a loop to add those in a layer. It works fine for a small dataset, now my dataset is more than 50K.

With this current approach my web browser is crashing.

I need solution or an approach to handle this situation.

My current dataset array looks like this,

```
var dataSetArray = [
   0:{
      latitude: 1.3023456,
      longitude: 103.830367
   },
]
```

I have array of 50K objects. 
I tried some approaches like,

1. Handling this data on server side.
2. Generating geoJson object (I am not sure how to do it.)

can anyone give me a approach or a solution, I am stuck on this from last four days.

I get two array one of 50K and other one of 20K. I first add 50 K array, (below is my code)

```
 var map = L.map('map', {
  center: L.latLng(1.241244, 103.718401),
  zoom: 18,
  layers: [tiles],
  zoomControl: false,
});

var options = {
  showCoverageOnHover: false,
  animateAddingMarkers: true,
  disableClusteringAtZoom: 17,
  chunkedLoading: true,
  chunkProgress: updateProgressBar,
  maxClusterRadius: 100
};

var markers = L.markerClusterGroup(options);
var LeafIcon = L.Icon.extend({
  options: {
    iconSize: [35, 35],
    iconAnchor: [0, 0],
    popupAnchor: [10, 2]
  }
});

var greenIcon = new LeafIcon({
 iconUrl: 'img/marker.svg'
});

var dataMarkers50K = [], dataMarkers20K = [];

for (var i = 0; i < dataPoints50K.length; i++) {
   var a = dataPoints50K[i];
   var dataMarker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a.latitude, a.longitude), {
     icon: greenIcon
   });
   dataMarkers50K.push(dataMarker);
}

for (var k = 0; k < dataPoints20K.length; k++) {
  var b = dataPoints20K[k];
  var contentString = '';

  if(b.content) contentString = b.content;

  var dataMarker_2 = L.marker(new L.LatLng(b.latitude, b.longitude), {
    icon: L.divIcon({
        className: 'label',
        html: b.content,
        iconSize: [45, 45],
        iconAnchor: [0, 0],
        popupAnchor: [15, 2]
      })
  });

  dataMarker_2.bindPopup(contentString);
  dataMarkers20K.push(dataMarker_2);
}

map.on('zoomend', function(e) {
  if(map.getZoom() > 16){
    markers.removeLayers(dataMarkers50K);
    markers.addLayers(dataMarkers20K);
  }else if(map.getZoom() <= 16){
    markers.removeLayers(dataMarkers20K);
    markers.addLayers(dataMarkers50K);
  }
});

markers.addLayers(dataMarkers50K);
map.addLayer(markers);
```

Let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does it work at least with marker cluster (without layer support)? If not, which version of marker cluster plugin do you use?

Comment: @ghybs I have one more requirement thats why I am using layer. I am removing these 50K data points and adding new 20K data points at a certain zoom level. can we do that in marker clusterl?

Comment: Try first to isolate what makes your browser crash: the fact that you have thousands of markers, or your additional requirement?

Comment: @ghybs thousands of markers crashing my browser.

Comment: Which version of marker cluster do you use? Do "[demos handling lots of markers](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#handling-lots-of-markers)" also crash your browser?

Comment: I am using 1.0.0-rc.1.0 version of marker cluster. I'll check above one.

Comment: @ghybs it works for 50K Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code, it is hard to say what you could improve already on client side.

For sure managing more data server side would help, but you need probably a good amount of work.

As for GeoJSON, I do not see how that could help.

A few things to check:

- Do you add all your markers once, using `addLayers()`, rather than one by one using `addLayer()`?
- Do you really need to remove your 50k markers and add the 20k others back-and-forth into a marker cluster? Would removing / adding directly to map (as 2 separate marker cluster groups) be enough?

Comment: Added the code in question, let me know what you think. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried creating 2 separate marker cluster groups (1 for your 50k, 1 for your 20k) and swapping them on map `"zoomend"`, instead of adding/removing arrays of markers into/from a group?